# JAXB binding the list of references to another element

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Its easier to explain with an example,

Sample XML:

```
<root>  
 <company>
        <name>xyz</name>
        <employees>
           <employeeref>emp1</employeeref>
           <employeeref>emp2</employeeref>
        </employees>   
 </company>

      <employee id="emp1">
         <name>a</name>
         <age>12</age>   </employee>

      <employee id="emp2">
         <name>b</name>
         <age>24</age>   </employee>

      <employee id="emp3">
         <name>c</name>
         <age>36</age>   
      </employee> 
</root>
```

This would need Company.java and Employee.java.

My question is,
How do i bind the xml to java objects using Jaxb annotations?

Comment: You can start here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JAXB/article.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@XmlID` in combination with `@XmlIDREF`

**Employee**

On the `Employee` class you need to annotate which field/property is going to be the "key" for the object.  In JAXB this is done with the `@XmlID` annotation.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Employee {

    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlID
    private String id;
}
```

**Company**

In the `Company` class we will indicate that we want to marshal instances of `Employee` as a reference to the real object.  This is done using the `@XmlIDREF` annotation.

```
@XmlAccesorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Company {

    @XmlElementWrapper
    @XmlElement(name="elementref")
    @XmlIDREF
    private List<Employee> employees;
}
```

**Root**

In order for `@XmlIDREF` to work the object must mapped somewhere else with an `@XmlElement` annotation.  In this example this happes in the `Root` class.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    private Company company;

    @XmlElement(name="employee")
    private List<Employee> employees;

}
```

**For More Information**

You can read more about `@XmlID` and `@XmlIDREF` on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-shared-references-xmlid-and.html

Comment: thanks doughan, I'm reading your blog specially for JAXB and MOXY

Answer (score -1):

I think you need following class, here is sample, you can do it with other ways

```
Root    One class for Root
    | -- Company  Company class
    |  |
    |  | employess(List)  one more class for employess collection
    |         
    |         
    employee (collection) one class for employee
```

**EmployeeData**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class EmployeeData {
    @XmlElement
    private Company company;
    private List<Employee> employee; 
// getter/setter
}
```

**Company**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Company {
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private String name;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private Employees employees;
//...// getter/setter
}
```

**Employee**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Employee {
        @XmlElement
    private String name;
    private int age;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    private String id;
///// getter/setter
}
```

**Employees**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Employees {
        private List<String> employeeref;
```

// getter/setter
    }

Comment: FYI - Here would be a better way to map this use case that takes into account the key/foreign key aspect:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23397293/383861

Answer (score -2):

Java classes can be structured in such a way that they form a tree hierarchy as described in the XML file. Annotations are used in the Java classes to describe this structure.
Here is a list of some annotations used:

- @XmlRootElement : Maps a class or an enum type to an XML element.
- @XmlAttribute : Maps a JavaBean property to a XML attribute.
- @XmlElement : Maps a JavaBean property to a XML element derived from property name

The **Employee** class can be like that:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Employee {
    private String id;

    private String name;

    private String age;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    @XmlAttribute
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```